# Configuring Sunspot to work with Solr on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, production

I'm relatively new to all this so please feel free to ask for clarification or more information if what I've arrayed here isn't useful!

I'm trying to use sunspot with solr, and have thus far followed steps 1 and 2 of [this guide](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way).

Other specs:

Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.1.1'

tomcat 6 and other info on that in linked guide

The database is working fine, as is tomcat and solr (they're accessible through the :8080 & :8080/solr urls respectively) so I suspect I've fudged up some configuration somewhere.

Currently I'm getting this error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
Error: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error report</title><style><!--H1   {font-family:Tahoma,A
rial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-
serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;colo
r:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;
background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.n
ame {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /solr/production
/select</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/solr/pr
oduction/select</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (/solr/production/select) is not
available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.35</h3></body></html>

    Request Data: "fq=type%3AItem&start=0&rows=4&q=%2A%3A%2A"
Backtrace: /home/deploy/socialnom_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client
.rb:283:in `adapt_response'
/home/deploy/socialnom_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/home/deploy/socialnom_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
etc
```

sunspot.yml:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production


development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
   log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

the conf and schema from my app are inside /usr/share/solr/conf and /usr/share/conf and I haven't touched those

Previously, before I fiddled around with everything, I was getting an ERRNO: PERMISSION DENIED or some sort of message like that, if that's informative at all.

Answer (score 0):

The port in your sunspot.yml and the port your Tomcat uses must be the same. You said that you can access solr through the 8080 port so in your sunspot.yml:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080 # This is the port of Tomcat
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
```

Tomcat runs under the tomcat6 user priviliges, so the `data` directory in `solr/production` must be writable by this user.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I hope my solution will help anyone.

If your sunspot.yml contains block like

```
production:
  solr:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 8080 # This is the port of Tomcat
  log_level: WARNING
  path: /solr/production
```

then check that sold.xml contains declaration of a core with the name `production`

```
<cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
  <core name="production" instanceDir="." dataDir="default/data"/>
  ...
</cores>
```